# replaceItemAtUrl working on simulator but not real iPhone

Tags: swift

For some reason `replaceItemAtUrl` is not working when I test my app on a real iPhone. It works on all simulated devices but not on the actual physical device. Phone and simulators are all running iOS 9.1

```
let documentsDirectoryURL =  NSFileManager().URLsForDirectory(.DocumentDirectory, inDomains: .UserDomainMask).first! as NSURL
    let fileManager: NSFileManager = NSFileManager.defaultManager()



    do {

        try NSFileManager().moveItemAtURL(location, toURL: documentsDirectoryURL.URLByAppendingPathComponent(downloadTask.response!.suggestedFilename!))
    }
    catch {
        print("did not copy file")


    }

    do {

        try fileManager.replaceItemAtURL(NSURL(fileURLWithPath: path!),
    withItemAtURL: documentsDirectoryURL.URLByAppendingPathComponent(downloadTask.response!.suggestedFilename!),
    backupItemName: nil,
    options:  NSFileManagerItemReplacementOptions.UsingNewMetadataOnly,
            resultingItemURL: nil)
        handleJsonUpdate()
    }
    catch {
        print("oops")


    }
```

prints "oops" on iPhone, but updates file on simulator. I tried copying the file first as you can see, which works on simulator....but again...not on phone.

Comment: In a do/catch block like this an ErrorType is created and available in the scope of the catch block. Try printing `print("opps", error)` for more details about why that operation failed on a device.

Comment: "replaceItemAtUrl is returning false" Makes no sense. `replaceItemAtURL` does not return a boolean value.